# Angular 5 Dynamic variable name

Tags: angular5

I want to call a variable dynamically.

```
export class AppComponent  {
  my_a_variable = 'test a';
  my_b_variable = 'test b';
  type = 'a'; // this variable value will come from another place dynamically.
}
```

In my html i need something like

```
<div>{{my_{{type}}_variable}}</div>
```

I know it can be solved with an assoc array but I can't use this here.
Can you please help?

Thanks.

Comment: This is already asked [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript)

Comment: @VipulSolanki this is about angular variable binding. nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hope this works,

```
export class AppComponent  {
 my_a_variable = 'test a';
 my_b_variable = 'test b';
 type = 'a';
}
```

In your template you can do like this,

```
<div>{{this['my_' + type + '_variable']}}</div>
```

Comment: what  is + type + syntax is  something related to sting interpolation,Any documention is encorged

Comment: @mdvenkatesh It is just the string concatenation