# Angular changing variable name dynamically

Tags: angular

I have a JSON Object in my app.component.ts with several values in it with different indices at the end like

```
 component.JSONObject.Q_HH_44
```

In a different post( [Angular 5 Dynamic variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49610238/angular-5-dynamic-variable-name) ) I read i could change the variable name dynamically in the HTML-Template like such:

```
{{this['component.JSONObject.Q_HH_' + component.id]}}
```

However this doesn't seem to work for me and I dont't get why. I think the problem is the
`this`
but without the string is written instead of dispayling the variable's value

Here's a Stackblitz with my struggle and all cases I thought could work
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zqlub5?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played with your stackblitz and got what you want:

```
<p>
  {{obj.col1['Attribute' + values[1]]}}
  <!-- only String -->
</p>
<p>
  {{obj.col1['Attribute' + values[1]]}}
  <!-- nothing at all -->
</p>
```

You can't use dots in string to get json objects, `js` doesn't work this way.